# Getting Error Code 1052. Column 'customer_id' in field list is ambiguous (new to coding)

Tags: sql

```
SELECT SUM(amount), customer_id FROM customer AS c 
  JOIN payment p 
    ON c.customer_id=p.customer_id
  GROUP BY customer_id, amount 
  ORDER BY customer_id 
  LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Ambiguous simply means that the column is found in both tables, need to _explicitly_ specify one or the other, maybe `c.customer_id` or `p.customer_id`? ... depends upon the need.

Answer (score 0):

Change `customer_id` to `p.customer_id` or `c.customer_id`  to remove ambiguity